# How to send data in PHP using a form?

Tags: php, jquery, html

i am having trouble sending data in PHP using a form i made up. For some reason nothing happens when i click the submit button.

I think the problem may be in my Jquery.main in the submit click area, or in the submit of the HTML form, or the use of $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].

I am testing using localhost, apache and using my own computer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Create New Account</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" media="all" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.inputfocus-0.9.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<?php

/**
 * @author Emile Jobity
 * @copyright 2012
 * @abstract displays a form, inserts data from the form to the database
 * @example http://webexpedition18.com/articles/how-to-create-a-multi-step-signup-form-with-css3-and-jquery/
 */

if (isset($_POST['submit'])):

  $username = "root";
$password = "xxxx";

//connection to the database
try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cwalcott_ei2', $username, $password);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
  $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $company = $_POST['company'];
  $phone = $_POST['phone'];
  $country = $_POST['country'];

 try{ 
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO user (username, password,firstname,lastname,email,company,phone,country,register_date) 
                            VALUES(:username,:password,:firstname,:lastname,:email,:company,:phone,:country,:register_date)');
  $stmt->execute(array(
    ':username' => $username,
    ':password' => $password,
    ':firstname' => $firstname,
    ':lastname' => $lastname,
    ':email' => $email,
    ':company' => $company,
    ':phone' => $phone,
    ':country' => $country,
    ':register_date' => NOW()
  ));
  # Affected Rows?
  echo $stmt->rowCount(); // 1
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>

<p><a href="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">Create an Account</a></p>

<?php
  else: // Allow the user to enter a new data
?>

<div id="container">
        <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">

            <!-- #first_step -->
            <div id="first_step">
                <h1>SIGN UP FOR A FREE <span>GOLDENICON</span> ACCOUNT</h1>

                <div class="form">
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="username" />
                    <label for="username">At least 4 characters. Uppercase letters, lowercase letters and numbers only.</label>

                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="password" />
                    <label for="password">At least 4 characters. Use a mix of upper and lowercase for a strong password.</label>

                    <input type="password" name="cpassword" id="cpassword" value="password" />
                    <label for="cpassword">If your passwords aren’t equal, you won’t be able to continue with signup.</label>
                </div>      <!-- clearfix --><div class="clear"></div><!-- /clearfix -->
                <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit_first" id="submit_first" value="" />
            </div>      <!-- clearfix --><div class="clear"></div><!-- /clearfix -->


            <!-- #second_step -->
            <div id="second_step">
                <h1>SIGN UP FOR A FREE <span>GOLDENICON</span> ACCOUNT</h1>

                <div class="form">
                    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="first name" />
                    <label for="firstname">Your First Name. </label>

                    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" value="last name" />
                    <label for="lastname">Your Last Name. </label>

                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="email address" />
                    <label for="email">Your email address. We send important administration notices to this address. </label>       

                </div>      <!-- clearfix --><div class="clear"></div><!-- /clearfix -->
                <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit_second" id="submit_second" value="" />
            </div>      <!-- clearfix --><div class="clear"></div><!-- /clearfix -->


            <!-- #third_step -->
            <div id="third_step">
                <h1>SIGN UP FOR A FREE <span>GOLDENICON</span> ACCOUNT</h1>

                <div class="form"> 
                    <input type="text" name="company" id="company" value="company" />
                    <label for="company">Your Comapny Name. </label>

                    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="phone" />
                    <label for="phone">Your Phone No.#. </label>

                    <select id="country" name="country">
                        <option>Trinidad and Tobago</option>
                        <option>United States</option>
                        <option>United Kingdom</option>
                        <option>Canada</option>   
                        <option>Caribbean</option>                     
                    </select>
                    <label for="country">Your country. </label> <!-- clearfix --><div class="clear"></div><!-- /clearfix -->

                </div>      <!-- clearfix --><div class="clear"></div><!-- /clearfix -->
                <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit_third" id="submit_third" value="" />

            </div>      <!-- clearfix --><div class="clear"></div><!-- /clearfix -->


            <!-- #fourth_step -->
            <div id="fourth_step">
                <h1>SIGN UP FOR A FREE <span>GOLDENICON</span> ACCOUNT</h1>

                <div class="form">
                    <h2>Summary</h2>

                    <table>
                        <tr><td>Username</td><td></td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Password</td><td></td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Email</td><td></td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Name</td><td></td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Company</td><td></td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Phone</td><td></td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Country</td><td></td></tr>
                    </table>
                </div>      <!-- clearfix --><div class="clear"></div><!-- /clearfix -->
                <input class="send submit" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="" />            
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="progress_bar">
        <div id="progress"></div>
        <div id="progress_text">0% Complete</div>
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Jquery.main

```
$(function(){
    //original field values
    var field_values = {
            //id        :  value
            'username'  : 'username',
            'password'  : 'password',
            'cpassword' : 'password',
            'firstname'  : 'first name',
            'lastname'  : 'last name',
            'company' : 'company',
            'phone'  : 'phone',
            'email'  : 'email address'
    };


    //inputfocus
    $('input#username').inputfocus({ value: field_values['username'] });
    $('input#password').inputfocus({ value: field_values['password'] });
    $('input#cpassword').inputfocus({ value: field_values['cpassword'] }); 
    $('input#lastname').inputfocus({ value: field_values['lastname'] });
    $('input#firstname').inputfocus({ value: field_values['firstname'] });
    $('input#company').inputfocus({ value: field_values['company'] });
    $('input#phone').inputfocus({ value: field_values['phone'] });
    $('input#email').inputfocus({ value: field_values['email'] }); 




    //reset progress bar
    $('#progress').css('width','0');
    $('#progress_text').html('0% Complete');

    //first_step
    $('form').submit(function(){ return false; });
    $('#submit_first').click(function(){
        //remove classes
        $('#first_step input').removeClass('error').removeClass('valid');

        //ckeck if inputs aren't empty
        var fields = $('#first_step input[type=text], #first_step input[type=password]');
        var error = 0;
        fields.each(function(){
            var value = $(this).val();
            if( value.length<4 || value==field_values[$(this).attr('id')] ) {
                $(this).addClass('error');
                $(this).effect("shake", { times:3 }, 50);

                error++;
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('valid');
            }
        });        

        if(!error) {
            if( $('#password').val() != $('#cpassword').val() ) {
                    $('#first_step input[type=password]').each(function(){
                        $(this).removeClass('valid').addClass('error');
                        $(this).effect("shake", { times:3 }, 50);
                    });

                    return false;
            } else {   
                //update progress bar
                $('#progress_text').html('33% Complete');
                $('#progress').css('width','113px');

                //slide steps
                $('#first_step').slideUp();
                $('#second_step').slideDown();     
            }               
        } else return false;
    });


    $('#submit_second').click(function(){
        //remove classes
        $('#second_step input').removeClass('error').removeClass('valid');

        var emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;  
        var fields = $('#second_step input[type=text]');
        var error = 0;
        fields.each(function(){
            var value = $(this).val();
            if( value.length<1 || value==field_values[$(this).attr('id')] || ( $(this).attr('id')=='email' && !emailPattern.test(value) ) ) {
                $(this).addClass('error');
                $(this).effect("shake", { times:3 }, 50);

                error++;
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('valid');
            }
        });

        if(!error) {
                //update progress bar
                $('#progress_text').html('66% Complete');
                $('#progress').css('width','226px');

                //slide steps
                $('#second_step').slideUp();
                $('#third_step').slideDown();     
        } else return false;

    });


    $('#submit_third').click(function(){
        //update progress bar
        $('#progress_text').html('100% Complete');
        $('#progress').css('width','339px');

        //prepare the fourth step
        var fields = new Array(
            $('#username').val(),
            $('#password').val(),
            $('#email').val(),
            $('#firstname').val() + ' ' + $('#lastname').val(),
            $('#company').val(),
            $('#phone').val(),
            $('#country').val()                       
        );
        var tr = $('#fourth_step tr');
        tr.each(function(){
            //alert( fields[$(this).index()] )
            $(this).children('td:nth-child(2)').html(fields[$(this).index()]);
        });

        //slide steps
        $('#third_step').slideUp();
        $('#fourth_step').slideDown();            
    });

/*
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        //send information to server
        alert('Submitting Data press Ok');
    });
*/
});
```

Comment: Nothing happens because of this line: `$('form').submit(function(){ return false; });` which cancels the form submission. Remove that line and your form will be submitted when clicking submit button. Good luck!

Comment: Unrelated, but perhaps consider _not_ using the `root` user when connecting to the db: perhaps create a user that can update, insert and delete records, but not drop tables for queries that deal with user input. Not that injection is an issue here, but it's just better to shield your system as much as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it work right using this in the Jquery main

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
        //send information to server
        $('form').unbind('submit').submit();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First, strip all the javascript and try if it works as pure HTML+PHP solution. Instead of the repeated submit button, I'd recommend using something like `<a href="#">Next Step</a>`, styled into the looks of a button. That way you don't have to care about the form submitting until the final step where submit button will be displayed/enabled after successfuly filled form.

Also, I'd recommend using an existing solution for form wizards. It's mostly easier to use something that has been done and tested - allows you to focus on the more crucial parts of development.

Answer (score 0):

you are using short opening tags

```
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
```

which is not recommended, and by default will be off.

To make sure that your form is getting value of action of form

change this

```
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
```

to this

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
```